# Nginx doesn't redirect on https

Tags: nginx, http, https

I want to redirect all requests to https. It works for main page now, so then I'm trying to get http://domain.com it redirects me to https. But then I go on sublink like http://domain.com/somematerials/presentation it never redirects me.
And here is my config.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen     443;
    server_name  my.domain.com;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /path/ssl.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/server.key;

    location / {
        root  /home/uploader/datadir/;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your port 80 server block is not the default. Try adding `default_server` in your port 80 definition.

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Below is the tested and properly working configuration:**

```
server {
listen 80; # Default listen port
server_name    mydomain.com;
return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
listen 443;
ssl on ;
server_name mydomain.com;;

....

}
```

**One more way to do this :**

```
server {
listen 80; # Default listen port
if ( $host = domain.com ) { rewrite ^/(.*)$ https://domain.com/$1 permanent; }
server_name domain.com;
......
}

server {
listen 443;
ssl on;
server_name domain.com;
ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/conf.d/certificates/domain.com.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/conf.d/certificates/domain.com.key;

.......
}
```

Comment: The first one is the better one, due it's lack of `if`. See "Server Name (If)" section of https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/

Answer (score 1):

The main problem to my eyes is that your not using the server_name directive at all so nginx doesn't know what its rewriting. With the SSL bit removed:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name *.mydomain.com mydomain.com
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
server {
  listen     443;
  #include snippets/certloc.conf
  server_name  my.domain.com;

  location / {
    root  /home/uploader/datadir/;
    index  index.html index.htm;
  }
}
```